# How to enable GZIP in compression on static Amazon S3 files using Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, compression, gzip, nuxtjs3

I am working on Nuxt 3 project and I want to use gzip to compress mu chunk size. It should add on response header.

[image: check this image]

I have used this [`https://nuxt.com/modules/precompress`](https://nuxt.com/modules/precompress) but not working and seems deprecated module.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance!